# Spring 5: How to disable standard Spring Security & Form Login, using custom auth

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a custom set of authentication calls and providers. When they fail, I want to only send a 401 back. I had this working in Spring 4/Springboot 1.5 by providing a custom SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler that wrote the 401 back to the response.

I'm migrating to Spring/Spring Security 5, and I've run into an issue where I can't seem to disable the default security mechanisms, specifically the ExceptionTranslationFilter which insists on taking the AccessDeniedException and throwing a ServletException if I commit the response previously, or overwriting it with a 403 if I don't.

Here's the relevant parts of my Security Config:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSec) throws Exception {
    final HttpSecurity.RequestMatcherConfigurer requestMatcherConfigurer = httpSec.requestMatchers();
    final ExpressionUrlAuthorizationConfigurer<HttpSecurity>.ExpressionInterceptUrlRegistry expressionInterceptUrlRegistry =
            requestMatcherConfigurer.and().authorizeRequests();
    expressionInterceptUrlRegistry
            .antMatchers("/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v*/**").authenticated()
            .antMatchers("/trace").permitAll();


    // disable sessions
    httpSec.sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);


    httpSec.formLogin().disable(); //added this when moving from Sp4 to 5, trying to disable.
    httpSec.httpBasic().disable();  //added this when moving from Sp4 to 5, trying to disable.

    httpSec.csrf().disable(); 
    httpSec.headers()
            .frameOptions().sameOrigin(); // TODO: revisit this
    AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter authFilter = authFilter();
    authFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(new MyAuthHandler());
    httpSec.addFilterBefore(
            authFilter,
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

}
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `org.springframework.security.web.AuthenticationEntryPoint` interface?

Comment: What do you want to do on AccessDeniedException?

Comment: return a 401, which my auth failure handler is doing.